# Remove object from array in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a MongoDB collection, with documents that have an array field with objects. I need to delete a specific object when 2 properties match.

I've tried using pull https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-pull

but it only allows me to remove the whole document property, or I'm using it wrong.

```
$node = Node::where('ports.number', $portNumber)->where('ports.ip', $portIp)->first();
```

Now I want to delete the port object inside the ports[] if the number and IP matches. Something like this, but with Eloquent:

```
if($ip && $number){
    unset($ports[$key])
}
```

Any comment appreciated.

Comment: please explain better your problem. You are getting a `Node` and you wrote you want to remove `port` object. What is the relationship between these two items?

Comment: sorry. Each node is a mongo document. Each node has an array field called ports, that possesses objects. I just need to delete one of those objects. I can handle the conditioning, but each attempt to remove only a single object from that array field, turned into deleting the whole document. I don't know if I make myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DB::collection('users')->where('name', 'John')->pull('messages', ['from' => 'Jane Doe', 'message' => 'Hi John']);
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Node` model does have (or should have) a one-to-many relationship with a `Post` model, you probably have this function in the `Node` model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Post', 'post_id');
}
```

Assuming that, to delete one record in the related model, you can access the model with the `posts` function, select the record/s you need and delete it/them.

With code:

```
// with ports() you get the related models of the Node
Node::ports()->where('number', $portNumber)->where('ip', $portIp)->delete();
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it wasn't build that way, so to do that I'll have to change a lot, but it is a solution if there's no other way around.

There's no Port model, ports exist as a JS object, saved inside a ports array, saved inside a Node document.

Comment: you can still create the models, they will not affect your website.